# irssi grep some pattern on history

Tags: grep, irc, irssi

I'm new to irssi and I couldn't figure out one feature (or task).

I know I can use Page+Up/Down to scroll back and forth on the chat history. I also know I can use /lastlog to dump the whole chat history to console.

However, I don't know how to dump the chat history and grep certain pattern. For example, if I want to review conversation with someone named, user-a. My intuitive way is "grep user-a " so it will output all history in that window contain user-a.

Is there such a feature in irssi or irc in general?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no such feature in "IRC in general"; IRC is just a protocol for exchanging messages and does not have logging of any kind. So all that depends on the specific client.

In irssi, though, you can do `/lastlog user-a` to search for that word.

If you want regexp search, there's `/last -regexp` too.

Comment: Use `/lastlog pattern 10` to search for the last 10 occurrences of `pattern`.